# Newman : no message in response when HTTP status is 400 ( in Postman I'v message in response )

Tags: newman

I prepare collection in *Postman* and *Newman*.

In situations when in reply "Bad Request" in newman wasn't any details what is happened out of short info **[400 Bad Request, 1.06GB, 338ms]**.

The same request in **postman** gave me message with extensive description

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "message": "01070151:3: Rule [/Common/my-irule] error: Unable to find pool ( my-pool) referenced at line 5: [active_members my-pool]",
    "errorStack": [],
    "apiError": 3
}
```

**I would like to get the same message in *newman* - Is it possible ?**

Answer (score 2):

Include the following test in the Tests section of request to get the response body in the command line.

```
tests["Response: " + responseBody] = true;
```

To log the request during the execution.

```
tests["Request: " + JSON.stringify(request)] = true;
```

Comment: I was just check it, and I saw finally error message - ufff. This is it - many thanks for your answer.

Comment: Ok. If this resolved your issue, make sure you check the answer.